# Strange behavior of capturing group in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Given the following simple regular expression which goal is to capture the text between quotes characters:

```
regexp = '"?(.+)"?'
```

When the input is something like:

```
"text"
```

The capturing group(1) has the following:

```
text"
```

I expected the group(1) to have `text` only (without the quotes). Could somebody explain what's going on and why the regular expression is capturing the `"` symbol even when it's outside the capturing group #1. Another strange behavior that I don't understand is why the second quote character is captured but not the first one given that both of them are optional. Finally I fixed it by using the following regex, but I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong:

```
regexp = '"?([^"]+)"?'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
regexp = '^"?(.*?)"?$'
```

Or, if the regex engine allows lookarounds

```
regexp = '(?<=^"?).*?(?="?$)'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `"?` - an optional `"` char
- `$` - end of string.
  **Explanation**

> why the regular expression is capturing the " symbol even when it's outside the capturing group #1

The `"?(.+)"?` pattern contains a [*greedy* dot matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) subpattern. A `.` can match a `"`, too. The `"?` is an *optional* subpattern. It means that if the previous subpattern is greedy (and `.+` is a greedy subpattern) and can match the subsequent subpattern (and `.` can match a `"`), the `.+` will take over that optional value.

The [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) is a correct way to match any characters but a certain one/range(s) of characters. `[^"]` will never match a `"`, so the last `"` will never get matched with this pattern.

> why the second quote character is captured but not the first one given that both of them are optional

The first `"?` comes before the greedy dot matching pattern. The engine sees the `"` (if it is in the string) and matches the quote with the first `"?`.

Answer (score 2):

[Quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions): they try to match as much text as possible. Because your last `"` is optional (you wrote `"?` in your regular expression), the `.+` will match it.

Using `[^"]` is one acceptable solution. The drawback is that your string cannot contain `"` characters (which may or may not be desirable, depending on the case).

Another is to make `"` required:

```
regexp = '"(.+)"'
```

Another one is to make the `+` non-greedy, by using `+?`. However you also need to add anchors `^` and `$` (or similar, depending on the context), otherwise it'll match only the first character (`t` in the case of `"test"`):

```
regexp = '^"?(.+?)"?$'
```

This regular expression allows `"` characters to be in the middle of the string, so that `"t"e"s"t"` will result in `t"e"s"t` being captured by the group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: updated answer. Hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

.+ is greedy. It'll collect everything including the ". Your final "? doesn't require that a quote be present, hence .+ includes the quote.

The first quote isn't captured because it's matched by the "?

Answer (score 0):

The regexp is greedy by default, it will try to match as much as possible as soon as possible.

Since your capturing group contains `.+`, this will match the ending parenthesis before the `"?`. Then, when exiting the group, it is at the end of your line, which is matched by the optional `"`.

Answer (score 0):

`.+` matches any character as long as it can (including the `"`). And when it reaches end of the input the `"?` is matching as it means the `"` is optional.

You should use "non greedy":

`regex
"(.+?)"`